# Number of solution of an analytic equation

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a complex analytic function $f:\mathcal{A}\subset\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ on an open connected subset of the complex plane with $\mathcal{A}\supset\mathbb{R}$, and the equation
\begin{equation}
f(\zeta)=z
\end{equation}
for $\zeta\in\mathcal{A}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$; also suppose that $f(\zeta)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $\zeta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is the number of solutions of this equation constant? If not, can we always find some $M>0$ such that the number of solutions is constant for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\operatorname{Im}z|<M$? Finally, if not, is there some proper class of analytic functions such that the equation above admits a constant number of solutions, at least for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\operatorname{Im}z|<M$?

Comment: Thus Picard great theorem says that you need to restrict to the rational functions (or to compact Riemann surfaces) or you'll have infinitely many zeros near $\infty$ for all but one value. Locally the zeros move continuously with $z$, even analytically away from the zeros of $f'$ (where two $z$-curves meet)

Comment: Thus the algebraic functions (there is a polynomial $P\in \Bbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $P(f,\zeta)=0$) work too

Comment: @reuns Thank you. How may I prove the claim in your second comment? Does it follow by showing that an algebraic function cannot have essential singularities at $\infty$?

Comment: The concept of (compact) Riemann surface $X_f=\{ (s,f_\gamma(s)),s\in \Bbb{C}\}$ helps, where $f_\gamma$ are all the branches of your algebraic function, for example $f_1=z^{1/2},f_2=-z^{1/2}$. This way $f$ becomes meromorphic $X_f\to \Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is true is that if $\Omega$ is a bounded open set with $\overline{\Omega} \subseteq \mathcal A$,  then the number of solutions (counted by multiplicity) of $f(\zeta) = z$ in $\Omega$ is constant on any connected open set of 
$z$ that does not intersect $f(\partial \Omega)$.

If you want to consider all of $\mathcal A$, you may run into trouble because

1. there may be infinitely many solutions (e.g. if $\mathcal A = \mathbb C$ and $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$,  Picard's "great" theorem says this will be the case with at most one exception).
2. Solutions can "run off to $\infty$".